# Prediction interval too big

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have been given some data to analyse and I need a prediction interval for a car park that has a maximum capacity of 500. My prediction interval is from 325 to 525. As it is impossible to have a value larger than 500 am I justified in changing the prediction interval from (325,525) to (325,500). If not why?

Comment: How did you obtain the prediction interval/what function is used for prediction?

Comment: I just used the predict function in R

Comment: Do you have some kind of a probability model going on? I guess you need some standard deviations on that etc.

Comment: No I just used the linear model function on my data set and then used the predict function on my linear model in R

Comment: There are assumptions built into that function, such as normality.  A random variable with a cutoff is not normal.

Comment: How did you proceed? What model was supplied to predict()? Which data and method were used for model fitting?

Comment: @Paul We have checked the assumptions required such as constant variance and zero expectation of the residuals. However our capacity is a fixed value but our interest is in the occupancy.